# How do I get PhantomJS to connect through a proxy list?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

I have a pet programming project going on at the moment and I am now at a dead end, I have scraped a proxy list site and have a working list that outputs in the correct format, however when I run it inline with phantomJS I get an error that appears every time.

this code throws the error up when set

> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=[serarg2,])

But this one works perfectly well connecting to my own proxy

> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = ['--proxy=192.168.1.231:3128','--proxy-type=http',])

Segarg2 is defined as follows (please be kind I am new to python, and it is messy)

```
FIX4 = "'"
FIXOR = random.choice(address)
FIXOR2 = FIXOR + FIX4
FIXOR3 = ','
print FIXOR2
LEGO = "'--proxy="
SPIDER = ", '--proxy-type=http'"
#USERAGENT STRING
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (random.choice(uas))

serarg2 = LEGO + FIXOR + FIX4 + SPIDER
```

when this outputs it comes back correctly though when tested with

> print ('TEST SERARG2') 
>   print serarg2

```
  TEST SERARG2
  '--proxy=193.178.187.136:53281', '--proxy-type=http'
```

But I end up with this error each time with the list proxys

> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=[serarg2,])
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
>       self.assert_process_still_running()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
>       % (self.path, return_code)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255

Please help me with this please, can it even be done?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is below. What works is below

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = ['--proxy=192.168.1.231:3128','--proxy-type=http',])
```

What your generate from code is

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = ["'--proxy=192.168.1.231:3128', '--proxy-type=http'",])
```

So instead of generate elements of array you are generating single element with string. You code should be below

```
FIXOR = random.choice(address)
LEGO = "--proxy="
SPIDER = "--proxy-type=http"
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (random.choice(uas))

serarg2 = [LEGO + FIXOR, SPIDER]

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = serarg2)
```

PS: Request you to use better variable naming and not use full caps.

Comment: Thankyou so much, first project is completed now :) seems i still have a way to go before i get the hang of this python thing :)